# Correlation Matrix with Lists or Can not create DataFrame with Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, data-science, finance

It's about a data project. I have a problem with types of variables and I guess I am missing something that I can not see. I am beginner at this topic any help would be appreciated.

I have 8 normalised arrays and I want to put them into a dataframe so I can create a correlation matrix. But I have this error.

```
> ValueError: Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional
```

I have tried to reshape my arrays but it did not work but I wanted to see that shape of arrays is equal or not so I wrote:

```
print(date.shape,normalised_snp.shape,normalised_twybp.shape,normalised_USInflation.shape,normalised_USGDP.shape,normalised_USInterest.shape,normalised_GlobalInflation.shape,normalised_GlobalGDP.shape)
```

Then my output is

```
> (4220, 1) (4220, 1) (4220, 1) (4220, 1) (4220, 1) (4220, 1) (4220, 1) (4220, 1)
```

After that I converted my arrays into a list and create a dataframe with those lists.

```
normalised_snp = normalised_snp.tolist()
normalised_tybp = normalised_tybp.tolist()
normalised_twybp = normalised_twybp.tolist()
normalised_USInflation = normalised_USInflation.tolist()
normalised_USGDP = normalised_USGDP.tolist()
normalised_USInterest = normalised_USInterest.tolist()
normalised_GlobalInflation = normalised_GlobalInflation.tolist()
normalised_GlobalGDP = normalised_GlobalGDP.tolist()
```

I constructed the data frame:

```
alldata = pd.DataFrame({'S&P 500 Price':normalised_snp,
                        '10 Year Bond Price': normalised_tybp,
                        '2 Year Bond Price' : normalised_twybp,
                        'US Inflation' : normalised_USInflation,
                        'US GDP' : normalised_USGDP,
                        'US Insterest' : normalised_USInterest,
                        'Global Inflation Rate' : normalised_GlobalInflation,
                        'Global GDP' : normalised_GlobalGDP})
```

After that I have contstructed my correlation matrix

```
correlation_matrix = alldata.corr()
print(correlation_matrix)
```

Since then I have no error but my correlation matrix looks empty

```
> Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Is the problem caused by list type? If it is how can I solve the value error that occurs when I try to construct a data frame with matrices?

Comment: You do not need to convert the arrays to lists. So skip that part. Pandas expects the arrays to be 1 D. But you are feeding it a 2D array. 1 column. use the `flatten` method for each column. `normalised_snp.flatten()`

Comment: After I applied .flatten() all my values converted to 0

Answer (score 0):

After I applied **.flatten()** all my values converted to 0
[Here it is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcuMV.png)

Comment: It looks like maybe you meant to edit your question or leave a comment on the question? You answered your own question, but it doesn't actually *answer the question*. It just adds additional information about the problem.